# SCCM - Configuration Item to check optional windows feature status

Tags: sccm

I have created a configuration item to check the status of the optional feature Internet Explorer.

The CI contains the following powershell script:

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 -Online
```

The CI has been added to a Configuration Baseline and deployed to a test machine.

Running this powershell code manually outputs the following on a test machine

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 -Online

FeatureName      : Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64
DisplayName      : Internet Explorer 11
Description      : Finds and displays information and Web sites on the Internet.
RestartRequired  : Required
State            : Disabled
CustomProperties :
                   \SoftBlockLink : http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=142507
```

and the related compliance rule is configured as follows:

[image]

I would assume this should result in being compliant - but actually it isn't.
I'm new to SCCM and therefor wondering if my rule is misconfigured.

Any ideas / input is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjusted the powershell script to just output the actual state.

```
(Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -FeatureName Internet-Explorer-Optional-amd64 -Online).State
```